# Cannot install sphinxbase (offline voice recognizer) on Windows

Tags: android, offline, voice-recognition

I am trying to develop an offline voice recognizer on android. After a few searching I found CMU Sphinx is used for this purpose.

I am trying to install it on Windows,
Here are the instructions that are quoted from its own web page:

```
  Windows

  In MS Windows (TM), under MS Visual Studio 2008 (or newer - we test with Visual C++ 2008 Express):

     -load sphinxbase.sln located in sphinxbase directory
     -compile all the projects in SphinxBase (from sphinxbase.sln)
     -load pocketsphinx.sln in pocketsphinx directory
     -compile all the projects in PocketSphinx
```

The problem is, there is no `sphinxbase.sln` anywhere! Am I understanding it wrong? Should I not see a file named `sphinxbase.sln` and execute it? Or what should I do? What are the steps?

This question may help other people who have also problem with installing Sphinx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do **not** need to compile sphinxbase on Windows in order to build applications for Android. You just need to unpack them. You can follow the instructions here to compile the sample application:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

To use sphixnbase on Windows you can download precompiled libraries here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8-win32.zip

To compile Sphinxbase from sources, download sources here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz

and compile them according to the instructions. The sphinxbase.sln file in right in the top folder after you unpack the sources. Probably you need to enable extensions in explorer in order to see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think the problem is, in the links you sent, (also I was using them) they have no .sln file in that folder. I found the same package (sphinxbase) from another source and ta-ta there is .sln folder. You can check there is no .sln in that zip!

Comment: There is no sln in precompiled binaries just because they are precompiled. For sln you need to download source (.tar.gz file)

Comment: Do you know how can I make a speech recognizer that listens all the time? I want to create an app that is waiting for speech of a specific keyword: and when the user says this keyword, the service becomes ready to receive user voice commands.

Comment: Sure, you can do that with CMUSphinx, however, it will require some C development. If you are proficient with C, start with setting up the demo and later you can proceed with keyword spotting feature. Keyword spotting was discussed frequently on CMUSphinx forum.